# Can't change monitor brightness

Tags: display, brightness

I've a Samsung SyncMaster B1930 Monitor. I've installed all the graphics drivers.

I'm unable to set or change the monitor brightness because it says that *MagicEco is ON*. I've also downloaded some of the drivers from Samsung's website but they doesn't seems to work too. Any Idea how should I *set the brightness* according to my requirement ?

Answer (score 16):

You have two options:

- To manually change brighness you have to disable MagicEco which is a powersaving option.
- With MagicEco enabled you have to adjust the power saving mode (100 %, 75 %, 50 % and off) to change the brightness.

Read the manual to locate those settings. If locating those settings is the problem, please leave a comment.

Comment: Alternatively called `Eco Saving Plus` on other Samsung monitors (see System settings)

Answer (score 3):

How to Locate Settings :

1. Go To Menu.
2. Go to "Setup and Reset" option.
3. Go to "Magic Eco" Option.
4. In magic Eco option Select "Power saving Off" Option.
5. Go to your Brightness Setting.

   It will enabled and you can change the Value.

Answer (score 1):

I have just been through this annoying hoop of not being able to adjust the brightness.  This much might help you - The five way button under the screen works on brightness and a couple of other functions if you just press one of the edge buttons from a normal screen and don't press the middle button to get into any kind of menu.  As far as I can work out you have to use the side to side (dimmer) control at least a couple of clicks on both in order for your changes to stay.
I also found a lock menu function and you might have that on - in menu screen press the right button for a second or two and then the  left button for five seconds until the menu disappears.  That seems to lock or unlock the settings made. it shows a padlock at the top of the menu if it is locked.

Answer (score 0):

Well as stated from the Samsung website this "MagicEco" feature “makes saving energy easy. It adjusts Samsung monitor’s brightness based on how much energy you want to save."

So I would assume there would be a setting on your computer based on as mentioned how much energy you are willing to save, so you could lower that requirement which in theory should allow you to change the brightness setting.

As for the drivers not working, I guess you could of downloaded the wrong version or something, here is the link to their site

http://www.samsung.com/my/support/model/LS19PUYKF/XM, let me know what errors you are having

Answer (score 0):

We have a different Samsung monitor which also was blocking any way to adjust brightness - did a System-Reset All and then the option was no longer grayed out/blocked.